# GTK delete event

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I use GTK# and I need to abort a thread when the main window is closed. The thread is attached to the inner widget of the main one. I was trying to use delete and destroy events. I failed.

```
public class MyClass {

        GLWidget widget= new AnyWidget();

        public GLWidget widget{
            get { return widget; }
        }
        private float red = 0.0f;

        public MyClass ()
        {
            Thread producer = new Thread (new ThreadStart (ThreadRun));
            producer.Start ();
            widget.DeleteEvent += delegate { // I don't know what event I should use
                producer.Abort ();
            };
        }

        public void ThreadRun()
        {
                    while (true) {
                 //TODO
                    }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I press close button my GTK# application is not being closed.

Comment: Can you post a simple twenty-line program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Rather than `Abort`ing your thread you should set `producer.IsBackground = true;' that way when the application is ready to close it won't hang your process

Answer (score 0):

declare your producer thread as a public member of the class.

```
public class MyClass {
            public Thread producer = new Thread (new ThreadStart (ThreadRun));
//... 

}
```

then you should add an event handler just as below:

```
protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    producer.Abort ();
}
```

lastly, simply assign it to your event

```
widget.DeleteEvent +=OnDeleteEvent;
```